# As beautiful a girl as *well might* be?

Tags: modal-verbs, idioms

She was as beautiful a girl as **well might** be in the whole wide world. (Garden of Love) by Jeniffer Jackson

This pattern is new to me.
Usually could is used .
Is "well might" used here to have the same meaning?

Comment: [Please use specific titles.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/please-use-specific-titles-dont-just-ask-is-this-grammatically-correct)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [conflation](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/conflate) of a fairly ordinary subjunctive use of *might* in a comparative construction with the stock expression *may/might (very) well be*.

```
She was as beautiful a girl as might      be.
                              +might well be.
```

The speaker probably drew *well* into the sentence under a vague sense that the *well* in *may/might well be* is some sort of an intensifier. It **is** an intensifier there, but what it intensifies is the speaker’s acknowledgment or concession that the predicate headed by *may/might* is not merely a remote possibility, but a significant possibility:

> He may be right.  ... *It is at least possible that he is right*.
>   He may well be right. ... *It is so likely that he is right that we must at least consider it.*

The use of *well* here must be considered a mistake.

One sentence is not much to go on; but this infelicity and the gee-whizziness of “in the whole wide world” suggest to me that this is either an unsophisticated writer, or a sophisticated writer deliberately mimicking the style of an unsophisticated one—perhaps for comic effect, perhaps to give a sense of character, perhaps to conform to a particular genre.

Comment: So you mean to say that ***well might*** structure is always wrong?

Comment: And I didn't get why in your quoted sentences using ***well*** is considered a mistake? From dictionary I get the meaning of "may well" is "probably"

Comment: @Man_From_India *Well might* by itself is just inverted; but *well might* in that context is a mistake. "She was as beautiful a girl as might very probably be" doesn't make any sense; the sense the author aims at is "She was as beautiful as it is possible to be"..

Comment: Thanks. But "might well" = "probably". If we substitute it, it will be "she was as beautiful a girl as probably be". It makes sense.

Comment: @Man_From_India Not in this context. It weakens the statement: "She was as beautiful girl as might be in the whole wide world - maybe."

Comment: @StoneyB then how would you salvage this sentence, preserving the "as...as might well be" structue.

Comment: @username901345 I wouldn't. The whole point of my answer is that I don't think the *might well be* construction belongs there at all.